# Gatsby slug broken

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I am setting up a blog on my Gatsby site. When I navigate to the blog from within my website, the content loads. But when I copy and paste the url of the blog to go there directly, the content will not load. Just the template will load. Here is the url: https://www.squarepatch.io/Instructions/blog/

Not sure what file is making this problem but here is my template file:

```
import React from "react";
import { graphql, Link } from "gatsby";
import styled from "styled-components"
import './item.css'
import Layout from "../components/layout";


class Blog extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const item = this.props.data.markdownRemark
    const siteTitle = this.props.data.site.siteMetadata.title

    return (

      <Layout location={this.props.location} title={siteTitle}>
        <Article>
          <Heading>
            <Title>{item.frontmatter.title}</Title>
            <Date>{item.frontmatter.date}</Date>
          </Heading>
          <Body>
            <Text dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.html }} />
          </Body>

          <Closing>
            <Questions>Have a question / comment / concern? Feel free to <Link to='/contact' style={{ fontWeight: `500`, fontStyle: `italic` }}>reach out!</Link></Questions>
          </Closing>
        </Article>
      </Layout>

    )
  }
}

export default Blog;

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query BlogBySlug($slug: String!) {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        title
      }
    }
    markdownRemark(fields: { slug: { eq: $slug } }) {
      html
      fields {
        slug
      }
      frontmatter {
        title
        date
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Here is the node file

```
const path = require(`path`)
const { createFilePath } = require(`gatsby-source-filesystem`)

exports.createPages = ({ graphql, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  const item = path.resolve(`./src/templates/item.js`)
  const blog = path.resolve(`./src/templates/blog.js`)
  return graphql(
    `
      {
        allMarkdownRemark(
          sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
          limit: 1000
        ) {
          edges {
            node {
              fields {
                slug
              }
              frontmatter {
                title
                posttype
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `
  ).then(result => {
    if (result.errors) {
      throw result.errors
    }

    // Create item posts pages.
    const posts = result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges

    posts.forEach((post, index) => {
      const previous = index === posts.length - 1 ? null : posts[index + 1].node
      const next = index === 0 ? null : posts[index - 1].node



      if (post.node.frontmatter.posttype === 'product') { //product post

      createPage({
        path: post.node.fields.slug,
        component: item,
        context: {
          slug: post.node.fields.slug,
          previous,
          next,
        },
      })

    } else { //blog post
      createPage({
        path: post.node.fields.slug,
        component: blog,
        context: {
          slug: post.node.fields.slug,
          previous,
          next,
        },
      })


    }


    })

    return null
  })
}

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions, getNode }) => {
  const { createNodeField } = actions

  if (node.internal.type === `MarkdownRemark`) {
    const value = createFilePath({ node, getNode })
    createNodeField({
      name: `slug`,
      node,
      value
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: You are retrieving a `null` value that makes a 404 in your request (`/blog/nulll`). Check out the network tab in the inspector. I need more information however, it seems that your query is someway wrong. If you provide more information (such as your query) I would try to answer your question properly.

Comment: Thank you. I just updated with the node file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` on the `Text` component which is a `styled-component` paragraph. The problem is that once the content is added you end up with p's from the content nested inside this p element. This is non-standard markup and thus browsers have to transform it into parseable markup.

In this manner, this kind of markup `<p><p></p></p>` will often be rendered as `<p></p><p></p>`.

This is actually exactly what happens in your case. I took the liberty of finding the GitHub repository for this project and ran the following experiment:

I built the projet and searched for the parent p element in the generated Gatsby html. Here it is:

[image: nested p elements can be found on the generated html]

The paragraph with the `blog__Text...` class is your styled-component p and you can clearly see that it contains other p elements which is non-standard.

Then, I opened this file with a web browser and inspected the generated markup:

[image: Browser un-nesting nested p elements]

**...Suprise !** Your `Text` component is now empty. The browser, not knowing any better choose to un-nest its content and append it right next to it. Once the component re-renders, it will not contain anything. As this is happening outside of React's boundaries, the component will not be rehydrated with new content as React has no idea that this just happened.

---

If you throttle your connection speed and try to access the page you can actually see the content for some time while the page is not fully loaded. This happens because Gatsby first outputs pure html to the browser before React takes over. You are then briefly seeing the broken html representation of your page until the component is rendered and everything falls appart.

## Solution

As you may have guessed by now, you shouldn't nest `p` elements. Instead, you should use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` on a parent div to your content.

Instead of:

```
 <Body>
     <Text dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.html }} />
 </Body>
```

Use:

```
 <Body>
     <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: item.html }} />
 </Body>
```

I tried just that and everything works as expected.